# how do i convert my pandas dataframe to 1nf? (To decrease the number of unique values in a column)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple columns with multiple values separated by `","`.

eg: `restaurant_type` column has values like `'Casual Dining'` as well as `'Cafe, Casual Dining'`.

This is causing issues while visualizing due to the existence of `87` unique values.

Comment: can you add example for your dataframe

Comment: From what I understood from your question, I believe that the explode() function can solve it. Maybe this answer will help you:  [sttackoverflow-Split (explode) pandas dataframe string entry to separate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680754/split-explode-pandas-dataframe-string-entry-to-separate-rows)

Answer (score 0):

```
https://www.pythonpool.com/python-code-to-convert-a-table-to-first-normal-form/


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['David', 'Glenn', 'Steve'], 'Subjects': [
    ['English', 'Math'], ['Math'], ['Science', 'English']]})

print(df)
lens = list(map(len, df['Subjects'].values))

res = pd.DataFrame({'Name': np.repeat(
    df['Name'], lens), 'Subject': np.concatenate(df['Subjects'].values)})

print(res)
```